# Can a node be in two different fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Can the same node join a channel in network A with its own trust root CA, and another channel in network B with its own trust root CA?

Think cross border networks governed by different consortiums/governance (operated by different trust root/issuer), can a node join channels from different "network" jurisdiction - seemed to imply the node can hold two identities, one issued by network A, and another by network B?

And if this cannot work, what are the core principles/concept that prevents this from working?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - Yes

Peers can join multiple channels and each channel can be managed by a different set of ordering nodes.  The channel config block used to join a peer to a channel contains all of the information required for a peer to connect to the ordering nodes for that channel and start receiving blocks.

The only caveat is that the names of channels a peer joins must be unique, meaning a peer cannot join both "channelA managed by ordererA" and "channelA managed by ordererB".

Comment: Is there known example or documentation on this? If this is true, then it means two disjoint fabric networks (different trust root CAs) can actually interoperate and perform asset swaps?